# How Queues behave in mule 4 multi workers API?

Tags: queue, mulesoft, jms-topic, anypoint-mq

I need bit clarification on Queues (JMS Queue/Anypoint MQ) behavior in cloud hub where the API is deployed on multiple workers.

I the API, source is Queue listener to a JMS/Anypoint MQ topic.

in Hybrid/RTF Model: Queue listener will be running on only primary node, so no duplicate processing happens.

in CloudHub: as the workers are independent runtimes, and same API is deployed to multiple workers, if message is be picked up from both the workers Queue listeners isn't causing duplicate processing ?
I know the message will not be processed multiple times but how does it handled by MuleSoft ?

Comment: I think it is a Queue, so It should not matter if it is multiple workers or even if it is two completely different applications, the message will only be processed by the one who polls it first.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'm listening on topic, multiple queues can pull same message. In this approach there is chance of getting same message on to different workers of the same API.

Comment: You question is not specific/detailed enough. JMS and Anypoint MQ use different connectors and features. Anypoint MQ is not JMS compatible, and doesn't support topics like JMS.